# Unknown error on pulumi fundamentals tutorial

Tags: pulumi

I'm trying the pulumi fundamentals tutorial and at the end when I added the 3 containers to the stack, I get an error running pulumi up:

```
Diagnostics:
  pulumi:pulumi:Stack (pulumi_tutorial-dev):
    error: update failed

  docker:index:Container (mongo_container):
    error: 1 error occurred:
        * container exited immediately
```

When I run the container manually like this `docker run pulumi/tutorial-pulumi-fundamentals-database-local` I get the following message:

```
WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/arm64/v8) does not match the detected host platform (linux/amd64/v3) and no specific platform was requested
exec /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error
```

Also there is nothing in the log file in /tmp even with the verbosity set to 11.

Comment: This is caused by your docker client pulling the wrong architecture. What OS and docker client are you using?

Comment: I'm on ubuntu using `Docker version 24.0.5, build 24.0.5-0ubuntu1~22.04.1`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that at the time you ran the command, pulumi/tutorial-pulumi-fundamentals-database-local was not published as a multiarch docker image, or did not include an image for arm64. However, I just tried it on arm64 (Apple M1) and it successfully pulled and ran an arm64/v8 variant.

I suspect that Pulumi has discovered the problem and published a multiarch image since you tried this. Impossible to tell from your post, since you did not include the version/checksum of the image you pulled. I recommend trying again...